# Git branch names strategy - per module or per developer?

Tags: git, version-control

In my team I have 3 developers. Our web system will have something about 50 different modules (time estimation: 5 days for 1 module).

After I create master and dev branch, what will be better: To create (during coding) 50 branches, each branch for each module (one by one of course). In this approach when developer start new module, he create branch for it and when he is done, he merge it to dev.

Or maybe better will be to create only 3 branches "developer1_name", "developer2_name", "developer3_name"? In second approach when developer1 start new module, he commit it to branch "developer1_name", and when module is done, he merge it to 'dev'.

Which approach is better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would advises you to create a branch per module. That way once the code is merged your dev can pass to another module/branch and if the code must be edit later (you never know) he can come back to it easily. 
Furthermore, a developer can work on multiple modules. If he's stuck and wait for help, for example.

Comment: additional: when module is done, we can merge branch to dev or master and delete branch :) (so we solve in this way problem witch too many branches in repo)

Answer (score 2):

The answer to "which is better" will almost always be 'it depends', and will vary depending on who you ask. Nevertheless, here's some guidance based on my experience.

I would NOT recommend a branch for each and every module if it's mostly new work. That's a lot of overhead for less return. IMHO it's better to let people contribute working code to the trunk (dev branch) as often as possible, and only create branches when needed. It's one extra step that doesn't always get you much, and I like to keep things as simple as possible until more complexity is needed. **Encourage your team to push often, and only ever push working code.** Then you've always got a working base without needing to sort through a merge process.

How interdependent are the modules? If they depend heavily on each other, you will probably want a single dev branch most of the time. Commit frequently and make sure the devs are constantly getting latest from the trunk.

If it's likely that changes or features for a module will require breaking changes, that's a good candidate for a branch.

Are you going to be releasing in stages? If you need a partial build that works but doesn't include all functionality, you will need branches for each release. If you find yourself building a module that needs a good while (say > 2 weeks) and/or something that includes significant, breaking changes, you will want a branch.